# Should I use an article for the word 'nature' here?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

I always have trouble when to use articles in sentences.

The sentence I am trying to write is 'Taking inspiration from Nature to address problems such as xyz...'

Should it be 'the nature' or 'Nature'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use an article unless you were taking about the "nature" of something.  "Taking inspiration from the nature of cats . . . " for example. Also, in most usages you would not capitalize the word nature. If you had a context where nature was being treated a deity, you might use a capital N.